# Sync issues using ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, synchronization

I am using ansible (linux) and running it against some envs (eg: ENV1, ENV2, ENV3, ENVX). I can run playbook1 in ENV1, ENV2 or ENV3.
At the end, playbook1 updates a file (filex.dat) which is located at ENVX, whether playbook1 is run in ENV1, ENV2 or ENV3.

The problem is that if I run playbook1 in ENV1 and ENV2 (at the same time), one of these runs can result in error because at the end both executions will try to update filex.dat. If they try to do it at the same time, the second execution will result in error because the file will be locked.

This is code causing the issue:

```yaml
- hosts: xpto
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Update filex.dat
      synchronize:
        src: "some/path1/v"
        dest: "some/path2/filex.dat"
```

Error:
"rsync: rename failed for filex.dat".

Is there any way to handle this?
Maybe setting some waiting mechanism when the file is already being accessed.

Possible solution:

```yaml
    - name: Wait until the file filex.dat is present before continuing
      wait_for:
        hosts: xpto
        path: some/path2/filex.dat
      delay: 1
      timeout: 10
     delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Update file filex.dat
    - hosts: xpto
      gather_facts: no
      tasks:
        - name: Update filex.dat
          synchronize:
            src: "some/path1/v"
            dest: "some/path2/filex.dat"
```

Comment: If you are using several target hosts, the above should not have any lock issue as you will be pushing the file to different host in parallel. Can you define as precisely as possible `the file is locked` (which one: target or source? what is the exact error message you get?...). Please do not reply in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72618968/edit) your question.

Comment: The issue is that If 2 playbooks are run at the same time, updating file filex.dat will result in error because one of execution is updating the file while the other can't. THe error I got it's this: "rsync: rename failed for filex.dat". Edited the error (the file is the same, in the same server: ENVX.

Comment: Please also add the fact you are running 2 playbooks in // inside your question. Meanwhile, the solution is simple: don't do that. Run everything from the same playbook and make sure concurrent operations are handled sequentially. Alternatively you can use something like the `wait_for` module to detect and wait for a file lock to be released before your start your synchronize operation.

Comment: I edit a possible solution. Is this as you mentioned?

Comment: Please don't edit a question with a possible solution. You are welcome to add a self answer if you believe it is solved and may help others. Meanwhile you should test and validate it before providing it to others.